# 'Resource is not a member of my' error in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, my.resources

Whilst loading up new resources to Visual Basic 2010 the IDE crashed half way and when I restarted it and tried to execute my program I get

> Resources is not a member of my

Could anyone help me figure out why the suddenly no more exists. Could it me a missing file? If so, which one.

I noticed that the size of resources.resx file had shrunk, so I restored a previous version from drop box but im still getting

> Resources is not a member of my

What other files could have possibly been affected and what would the purpose of these files be fore future reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried tracking down which resource it can't find and manually adding it back to the project through the resources interface?

Comment: The message is accurate, it is Resources.  Note the S at the end.

Comment: Corrected my message above. The error does say resources

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by watching the task manager. Seems the system was running out of memory on start up. I removed some surprisingly large resource files and this seems to have resolved the issue.